# How to get data from droptable from each v-for item in a component?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that's a list of shopping cart items being ran through a v-for and a v-select in each iteration.

I need to extract the "size" value from each loop variable. I'll be sending IDs and sizes to the database in this type of format `{items: [1,2,3], sizes: [34,46,28]}`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: So, each item ID and item size are a pair, right? and you want to render `v-select` options per each item ID az `value` and item size as option text. Is this correct?

Comment: It's better if you create an online sandbox or put your current code here, so anybody can have an initial understanding

Answer (score 1):

I found a quite simple solution here: https://vue-select.org/guide/loops.html

Essentially, you can handle @input with an anonymous inline function so you can pass the parameters that you need, like this:

```
<v-select
      :sizes="[1,2,3]"
      :value="item.size"
      @input="size => changeSize(item, size)"
    />
```